# React native Custom Functions with Param for component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am currently working on a react native project and I wanted a **separate button component**. Please find below the code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity } from from 'react-native'

const MyCustomButton = (props) => {
    return ('
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onButtonPressed}>
            <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ')
}

export default MyCustomButton
```

I use the above custom component like this.

```
<MyCustomButton
    title="Simple Button"
    onButtonPressed = {() => {
        //  code on buttonPressed
    }}
/>
```

**My question is how am I able to create a custom event onCustomFunctionButtonPressed with parameters like in below example.**

```js
    <MyCustomButton
        title="Simple Button"
        onButtonPressed = {() => {
            //  code on buttonPressed
        }}
        onCustomFunctionButtonPressed = {(buttonTitle) => {
            // code for custom button with params
        }}
    />
```

Please help me with this as I am new in react native.

Thanks

Comment: can you sepecify why do you want something like this??

Comment: this was the requirement from the client. As i am new in react native, i have no idea whether it is possible or not :(

Comment: This is what you want
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497090/react-how-to-pass-props-from-onclick-to-function

Comment: @Andus: actually i want to write a function which returns value from component (Similar to get method).

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. What have you tried already? What, if any, is the issue? Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do. In this case you only need to attach the passed `onCustomFunctionButtonPressed` callback to a DOM element that is interactable/clickable and pass the value back out. TBH you don't even need to pass the button title back out since it's in scope here in the parent component where you're passing it as a prop, just reference it.

Comment: could you please send us an example code

Comment: can you elaborate more on what do you want to return?

Comment: "could you please send us an example code" that's literally the thing you should provide in your question so we understand better what you're trying to do or accomplish.